# How to use connected component labeling?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.2 Android Java and I need to use `Imgproc.connectedcomponent` method which is implemented in this version of OpenCV, but the problem is I am not finding the way to get the labels of the labeled image returned. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [opencv 3.1 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#connectedComponents-org.opencv.core.Mat-org.opencv.core.Mat-) with function descriptions. It should be similiar the the 3.3 version. In addition you can find [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39789954/6718640) how to use the `connectedComponents` (its in C++).